# SQL Query to fetch data from the last 30 days?

Tags: oracle, datetime

Hi I am new to Oracle. How do I do a simple statement, for example get product id from the last 30, or 20 days purchase date?

```
SELECT productid FROM product
WHERE purchase_date ?
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
SELECT productid FROM product WHERE purchase_date > sysdate-30
```

Comment: How about this: "between SYSDATE and SYSDATE - 30"??

Comment: or how do I specify the date manually? like BETWEEN '2011-3-3' and '2011-2-3'?

Comment: @miracle `select productid  FROM product where purchase_date  between  to_date('2011-02-03','YYYY-MM-DD') AND  to_date( '2011-03-03','YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: @miracle: To answer those questions, if using `BETWEEN`, use `BETWEEN SYSDATE-30 AND SYSDATE` (the earliest one comes first). To specify a date literal, either use the ANSI date literal `date '2011-03-03'` or the to_date function e.g., `to_date('03-03-2011','DD-MM-YYYY')`.... or maybe modify your question if you want to know all that...

Answer (score 19):

The easiest way would be to specify

> SELECT productid FROM product where
>   purchase_date > sysdate-30;

Remember this sysdate above has the time component, so it will be purchase orders newer than 03-06-2011 8:54 AM based on the time now.

If you want to remove the time conponent when comparing..

```
SELECT productid FROM product where purchase_date > trunc(sysdate-30);
```

And (based on your comments), if you want to specify a particular date, **make sure you use to_date and not rely on the default session parameters.**

> SELECT productid FROM product where
>   purchase_date >
>   to_date('03/06/2011','mm/dd/yyyy')

And regardng the between (sysdate-30) - (sysdate) comment, for orders you should be ok with usin just the sysdate condition unless you can have orders with order_dates in the future.

Answer (score 10):

Pay attention to one aspect when doing "purchase_date>(sysdate-30)": "sysdate" is the current date, hour, minute and second. So "sysdate-30" is not exactly "30 days ago", but "30 days ago at this exact hour".

If your purchase dates have 00.00.00 in hours, minutes, seconds, better doing:

```
where trunc(purchase_date)>trunc(sysdate-30)
```

(this doesn't take hours, minutes and seconds into account).

Comment: "where purchase_date > trunc(sysdate-30)" also does the trick and can use an index if one exists (whereas your expression is difficult to optimize).

Answer (score 2):

Try this : Using this you can select data from last 30 days

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    product
WHERE
    purchase_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(job_id) FROM jobs WHERE posted_date < NOW()-30;
```

`Now()` returns the current Date and Time.

Comment: Oracle doesn't appear to have a NOW() function. I also tried without the parentheses. CURRENT_DATE or SYSDATE may do the job.

Answer (score -1):

```
select status, timeplaced 
from orders 
where TIMEPLACED>'2017-06-12 00:00:00'
```